# Authentication token for a React App

Tags: javascript, api

I am building an React JS app that has to receive data from online database. The API of the database asks for a me to provide a token.

https://api.thetvdb.com/swagger#!/Authentication/get_refresh_token

I have worked with Google Maps API where I can just click a button and get a token. But now I am confused about the following:

- Where can I obtain JWT token?

Answer (score 0):

You can get it from the `login` api as mentioned in the docs https://api.thetvdb.com/swagger#!/Authentication/post_login